# Prove that the set $E = \{X \in P(\Bbb{N}) | \sum_{n\in X} \frac1n \le 1\}$ has the size of the reals

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

I want to prove that the following set has cardinality $2^{\aleph_0}=|\mathcal P (\mathbb N)|=|\mathbb R|$ using the CSB Theorem.

**$E = \{X \in P(\Bbb{N}) | \sum_{n\in X} \frac1n \le 1\}$**

I know that $E\le|\mathcal P (\mathbb N)|$ as $E \subset P(N)$. I was thinking about finding an injection $f : A \to E$ such that $|A|=|\mathbb R|$. I was thinking about $A=(0,1]$ but I'm not able to find a specific injection.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Your question is unclear for several reasons: first of all, $\aleph$ is not a cardinal, it is a function enumerating them. The only way I find to make your question sensible is to assume that you meant $\aleph_1$ and $\aleph_1=2^{\aleph_0}$, which is not elementary set theory.

Comment: I have changed my question accordingly. I apologize for this mistake. I'm new to the community.

Comment: Mention of $\aleph_1$ is distracting nonsense. The symbol $\aleph$ is used in some places to denote the size of the reals (or, equivalently, of the power set of the natural numbers), so that seems to be what you meant from the beginning. I've edited the post accordingly. It is more common to use $2^{\aleph_0}$ than $\aleph $, so I changed that too, to avoid poor advice as in the first comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: It suffices to find one infinite $X \subseteq \mathbb N$ such that
$$
\sum_{n \in X} \frac{1}{n} \le 1. \tag{$\dagger$}
$$
Then every subset $X' \subseteq X$ satisfies $(\dagger)$ as well and an easy argument shows that there is a bijection $\mathcal P(\mathbb N) \cong \mathcal P(X)$.

Comment: The assumption that $2^{\aleph_0}= \aleph_1$ doesn't play a role in this argument. You'll always get that the set in question has cardinality $2^{\aleph_0}$ -- no matter what aleph number that happens to be. I also don't think that CSB is all that helpful here. Sure, you could rephrase this argument to use CSB -- but I don't think that there is an *elegant* proof along this route.

Comment: Thank you, but I need an injection $\mathcal P(\mathbb N) \to E$ and not $\mathcal P(X)$ or maybe I misunderstood your solution.

Comment: @MUSHDAN $\mathcal P(X) \subseteq E$ for some such $X$ and there is a bijection $\mathcal P(\mathbb N) \to \mathcal P(X)$. This very function is an injection $\mathcal P(\mathbb N) \to E$.

Comment: I think I got it. So the following would be a good injection, right? $\sum_{n \in X} \frac{1}{n^2}. \tag{$\dagger$}$ as $n\in$ A $\in\mathcal P(\mathbb N)$

Comment: @MUSHDAN I think you need to think this through a while longer...

Comment: I meant - 
$\sum_{n \in X} \frac{1}{2^n}$

Comment: Stefan, the mention of CH was not there originally, and was only introduced as a consequence of bad advice by someone who wasn't familiar with the notation $\aleph $ to denote $\mathfrak c $.

Comment: @Andrés I see. Thanks for clearing that up.

Comment: @MUSHDAN I'd really prefer not to give additional hints. All the puzzle pieces are there and I think it best to leave it to you to assemble them. However, if you really get stuck (e.g. you can't find some such $X$), don't hesitate -- after you've carefully thought about it -- to ask additional follow-up questions. (And those should probably be posted as separate questions linking to this one.)